# How "trustworthy" are chipset PSU voltage sensors?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, freeze

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a PC whose components are approximately 6-12 years old (the PSU is an Antec True550 550W, circa 2004; the motherboard is an Asus P5N-D from sometime around 2009; the video card is an OEM Radeon HD5670 circa 2014).

The problem: it seems to run fine, then randomly freezes (no reboot or obvious screen corruption... it literally just freezes "mid-heartbeat" without warning under both Windows 7 and Linux [Kubuntu 17.10.1]).

At the moment, I'm exploring what I think are probably the two most likely culprits... the electrolytic capacitors on the motherboard, and the PSU.

I didn't notice any blatantly-burst electrolytic capacitors... but I also noticed that the capacitors (unlike past motherboards) don't look like they CAN easily (and visibly) burst... it's almost like they have a secondary canister over them to catch anything that bursts (possibly improving safety, but also likely to make it harder to spot obviously bad caps). So for now, I'm keeping them in mind as a possibility, but moving on to other things.

Using KDE's system monitor app, I noticed that the voltages reported by the chipset are definitely on the low side.

The actual kernel names for the sensors I'm looking at are in the form lmsensors/atk0110-acpi-0/* (where "*" = "+12V_Voltage", "+5V_Voltage", and "+3.3V_Voltage").

```
+12v: 11.6v

+5v: 4.8v

+3.3v: 3.0v
```

HOWEVER, nothing I did (including burning a DVD) really seemed to make much of a difference to the reported voltage levels. In other words, they're all low... but they seem to be stable at that low point.

How likely does it seem that the PSU is the culprit (and just as importantly, that the values being reported by the motherboard chipset are accurate)? If newer caps are made to fail in less visibly-blatant ways than old ones, is there any straightforward way to determine whether they're good or bad?

Comment: [ATX spec](http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Catx2_2.PDF) says +12VDC has a +/- 5 % tolerance so technically 11.6 V is within tolerance. The +5VDC looks to be within spec too, and the +3.3VDC is maybe a bit low but not really important in a modern system. That said, I'm generally suspicious of a 14 year old PSU. Can you take some photos of the motherboard capacitors? What's your boot media (HDD? SSD?) and how old is it?

Comment: Your Radeon is probably shot.  OEM Radeons have always run 90+ degrees and cooked themselves for me every few years.  That is why my current one is an "overclocker" board so it has extra cooling capacity so when I run it at a stock clock, it runs much cooler and should not cook itself.

Comment: Your board might have [Polymer Capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_capacitor). They don't leak like the other electrolytics. Have you tested the memory at all? These kinds of issues are predominantly just lose and bad connections on the RAM after years of expansion and contraction. Remove it and clean it with contact cleaner and test it thoroughly.